# How to give a letter input a number value

Tags: java, string, variables, calculator, declare

So i am trying to make a simple program that uses a user input which will be a letter and number and make the program read it as a number so at the end the numbers get added. Let me give an example. If the user inputs A1 i want the program to read it as 100 and A2 as 90 for example. At the end I want the program to add these values and give the user and answer. This is what i have:

```
public class LCCalcMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input1, input2, answer;
        System.out.println("1st result");
        input1 = input.nextLine();
        input1 = System.out.println("2nd result");
        input2 = input.nextLine();
        int A1, A2, B1;
        A1 = 100;
        A2 = 90;
        B1 = 85;
        answer = input1 + input2;
        System.out.println(answer); 
    }
}
```

So i want them to enter like A1 and my program will read it as 100. So i can easily add everything at the end and give them an answer.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you make a more specific question, like a) what did you try b) what did you expect to happen c) how did it fail?

Comment: You cannot declare several variables and then use user input to pick one of the variables by name.  If you want the user to enter a string and have the program find an associated number, use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: I will look into hash map as im not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do an if/else case per input:

```
int currentValue1;//new variable
input1 = input.nextLine();
if("A1".equals(input1)){
    currentValue = 100;
}else if("A2".equals(input1)){
    //do another case
}else if("B1".equals(input1)){
    //do another case
}

int currentValue2;//new variable
input2 = input.nextLine();
if("A1".equals(input2)){
    currentValue2 = 100;
}else if("A2".equals(input2)){
    //do another case
}else if("B1".equals(input2)){
    //do another case
}

answer = input1 + input2;
System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: Using this technique just prints out whatever i enter like A1 or A2. For example if 1st input is A1 and 2nd input is A2. A1 being 100 and A2 being 90, i want my answer to be 190.

Comment: Could you use this in a loop until you are finished reading and keep a variable that you add your results to in order to get your final answer?

Comment: @user3117051 I'm kind of confused at what your question is now.  This does exactly as you're describing.